How exactly the forward and backward hooks work in PyTorch
I am trying to understand how exactly code-wise the hooks operate in PyTorch. I have a model and I would like to set a forward and backward hook in my code. I would like to set a hook in my model after a specific layer and I guess the easiest way is to set a hook to this specific module. This introductory video warns that the backward module contains a bug, but I am not sure if that is still the case.
My code looks as follows:
def __init__(self, model, attention_layer_name='desired_name_module',discard_ratio=0.9):
  self.model = model
  self.discard_ratio = discard_ratio
  for name, module in self.model.named_modules():
    if attention_layer_name in name:
        module.register_forward_hook(self.get_attention)
        module.register_backward_hook(self.get_attention_gradient)

  self.attentions = []
  self.attention_gradients = []

def get_attention(self, module, input, output):
  self.attentions.append(output.cpu())

def get_attention_gradient(self, module, grad_input, grad_output):
  self.attention_gradients.append(grad_input[0].cpu())

def __call__(self, input_tensor, category_index):
  self.model.zero_grad()
  output = self.model(input_tensor)
  loss = ...
  loss.backward()

I am puzzled to understand how code-wise the following lines work:
module.register_forward_hook(self.get_attention)
module.register_backward_hook(self.get_attention_gradient)

I am registering a hook to my desired module, however, then, I am calling a function in each case without any input. My question is Python-wise, how does this call work exactly? How the arguments of the register_forward_hook and register_backward_hook operate when the function it's called?

How does a hook work?
A hook allows you to execute a specific function - referred to as a "callback" - when a particular action has been performed. In this case, you are expecting self.get_attention to be called once the forward function of module has been accessed. To give a minimal example of how a hook would look like. I define a simple class on which you can register new callbacks through register_hook, then when the instance is called (via __call__), all hooks will be called with the provided arguments:
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hooks = []
    
    def register_hook(self, hook):
        self.hooks.append(hook)

    def __call__(self, x, y):
        print('instance called')
        for hook in self.hooks:
            hook(x, y)

First, implement two hooks for demonstration purposes:
def foo(x, y):
    print(f'foo called with {x} and {y}')
def bar(x, _):
    print(f'bar called with {x}')

And initialize an instance of Obj:
obj = Obj()

You can register a hook and call the instance:
>>> obj.register_hook(foo)
>>> obj('yes', 'no')
instance called
foo called with yes and no

You can add hooks on top and call again to compare, here both hooks are triggered:
>>> obj.register_hook(bar)
>>> obj('yes', 'no')
instance called
foo called with yes and no
bar called with yes


Using hooks in PyTorch
There are two primary hooks in PyTorch: forward and backward. You also have pre- and post-hooks. Additionally there exists hooks on other actions such as load_state_dict...

To attach a hook on the forward process of a nn.Module, you should use register_forward_hook, the argument is a callback function that expects module, args, and output. This callback will be triggered on every forward execution.

For backward hooks, you should use register_full_backward_hook, the registered hook expects three arguments: module, grad_input, and grad_output. As of recent PyTorch versions, register_backward_hook has been deprecated and should not be used.


One side effect here is that you are registering the hook with self.get_attention and self.get_attention_gradient. The function passed to the register handler is not unbound to the class instance! In other words, on execution, these will be called without the self argument like:
self.get_attention(module, input, output)
self.get_attention_gradient(module, grad_input, grad_output)

This will fail. A simple way to fix this is to wrap the hook with a lambda when you register it:
module.register_forward_hook(
    lambda *args, **kwargs: Routine.get_attention(self, *args, **kwargs))

All in all, your class could look like this:
class Routine:
    def __init__(self, model, attention_layer_name):
        self.model = model

        for name, module in self.model.named_modules():
            if attention_layer_name in name:
                module.register_forward_hook(
                    lambda *args, **kwargs: Routine.get_attention(self, *args, **kwargs))
                module.register_full_backward_hook(
                    lambda *args, **kwargs: Routine.get_attention_gradient(self, *args, **kwargs))

        self.attentions = []
        self.attention_gradients = []

    def get_attention(self, module, input, output):
        self.attentions.append(output.cpu())

    def get_attention_gradient(self, module, grad_input, grad_output):
        self.attention_gradients.append(grad_input[0].cpu())

    def __call__(self, input_tensor):
        self.model.zero_grad()
        output = self.model(input_tensor)
        loss = output.mean()
        loss.backward()

When initialized with a single linear layer model:
routine = Routine(nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10,10)), attention_layer_name='0')

You can call the instance, this will first trigger the forward hook with (because of self.model(input_tensor), and then the backward hook (because of loss.backward()).
>>> routine(torch.rand(1,10, requires_grad=True))

Following your implementation, your forward hook is caching the output of the "attention_layer_name" layer in self.attentions.
>>> routine.attentions
[tensor([[-0.3137, -0.2265, -0.2197,  0.2211, -0.6700, 
          -0.5034, -0.1878, -1.1334,  0.2025,  0.8679]], grad_fn=<...>)]

Similarly for the self.attention_gradients:
>>> routine.attentions_gradients
[tensor([[-0.0501,  0.0393,  0.0353, -0.0257,  0.0083,  
           0.0426, -0.0004, -0.0095, -0.0759, -0.0213]])] 


It is important to note that the cached outputs and gradients will remain in self.attentions and self.attentions_gradients and get appended on every execution of Routine.__call__.

Nice sharing !
One suggestion - extract register calls from __init__() to ensure PyTorch can serialize model for saving it; it meight fail to pickle these hooks.
Create hook and unhook functions to take care both of registering hooks and removing their handlers.
For your reference:
class FooNet(nn.Module):
def hook_backward(self, module, grad_input, grad_output):
    self.logg_grad_output = torch.stack(grad_output)

def hook_forward(self, module, args, output):
    self.logg_forward_output = torch.stack(output)

def __init__(self, num_class=10):
    super().__init__()
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.LazyConv2d(6, kernel_size=5, padding=2), 
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.LazyConv2d(16, kernel_size=5), 
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.LazyLinear(128), 
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.LazyLinear(64), 
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.LazyLinear(num_class))
    
def hook(self, idx_layer_hook=-1, enable_hook_fp=False, enable_hook_bp=True):
    if enable_hook_fp:
        self.logg_forward_args   = []
        self.logg_forward_output = []
        self.handler_fp = None
    if enable_hook_bp:
        self.handler_bp = None
        self.logg_grad_input     = []
        self.logg_grad_output    = []

    for idxx, layer in enumerate(self.net):
        if isinstance(layer,nn.Conv2d) and (idx_layer_hook != -1 and idx_layer_hook == idxx):
            print(f"Hook layer[{idxx}]:", layer)
            if enable_hook_fp:
                self.handler_fp = layer.register_forward_hook(lambda *args,**kwargs:LeNet.hook_forward(self,*args,**kwargs))
            if enable_hook_bp:
                self.handler_bp = layer.register_full_backward_hook(lambda *args,**kwargs:LeNet.hook_backward(self,*args,**kwargs))

def unhook(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'handler_fp'):
        self.handler_fp.remove()
    if hasattr(self, 'handler_bp'):
        self.handler_bp.remove()    

def forward(self, x):
    assert hasattr(self, 'net')
    x = self.net(x)  
    return x

As long as grad got logged, we can review it
gg = nw.logg_grad_output[0,0,0,:,:].numpy() 
str_title = "grad_layer%d"%(IDX_OF_LAYER_HOOK);
plt.style.use('grayscale')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2));
fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title(str_title);
ax.imshow(gg);
ax.set_title(str_title);
plt.show();    


